# How to change SaveButton icon in React-Admin

Tags: react-admin

Looks like the  component has the icon hard-coded(That icon that looks like a floppy disk), is there no way to pass in an icon as a prop and have it render that one instead?

Is there an easy way to do this for specifically React-Admin components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be possible in the next major version: `2.5.0` (see https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/2556).

Until then, you can implement your own button using material-ui by looking at the code (https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-ui-materialui/src/button/SaveButton.js)

Comment: Thanks, I went with the custom button option a long while back, forgot to update this question. Appreciate it!